# How to use Ajax and Jquery to append information

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code with jquery what it works correctly

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
                url:   'obtenerPaises',
                type:  'get',
                success:  function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
        });
  </script>
```

But I need to use an autocomplete plugin in jquery-ui, how can I append the information I recieve in the data to the following code ?

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Ok so why don't you set your ajax request as source option of autocomplete plugin???

Comment: Create the availableTags as a global variable, var it outside of the $(function...) then append to the array with .push(newTag).  Then you just push the new info onto it.  You'll have to re-bind with the new tags each time you change it.

Comment: @nurdyguy wouldn't that need a bit more management (since constant pushing to an array would cause double, triple. etc. instances of the AJAX object response? If the static list is created on the server instead and then issued to the client through the answer I described below, it would result in the same behavior and a single point of management... right?

Comment: @BlakeNeal  My understanding of the OP was that the AJAX would basically get a couple more tags, not a complete list.  Thus keeping a complete list and appending the new ones as you go.  Yes, you'll have to deal with dups but that isn't all that hard (can be done in 2-3 lines if you are sneaky).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `jQuery-UI` built in function for this. You can read more here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON('obtenerPaises', {}, response);
    },
    minLenght: 0,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        //here comes what happens if a user selected an item
    },
    response: function (event, ui) {
        //when server response
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        //It is trigger when the menu is closed
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [jQuery UI Autocomplete docs](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp), you can use the GET AJAX request as the data source. JSONP is a cross-domain-safe GET-specific request type that will convert your data object (an array in this case) from the server to the list used by your widget. So it will look something like this:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
            url:   'obtenerPaises',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success:  function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
  }
});
```